# Can akka actors pass messages back to the client a scenerio like this

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I have some pseudo code that I was hoping some with experience could tell me if akka would be used like this, and if not, how I could re-work my design to fit into akka's best practice.

```
class Article(val words: Word) {

  val tokens: List[Word]

}

class Word(..) {


  def parseWords() {
    val word = .....
    tokenActor ! word    // this is suppose to add the word to the tokens List

  }

}
```

So the pattern is basically I will create a `Article` which will have a `word` object.  Then the  `word` object will start doing some parsing, and at times it needs to pass data back to the `Article` object to "share memory by communicating" like in Go's coroutines.

I know Scala had an inbox type system but not going forward we are suppose to use Akka, but I find that Akka has poor documention when it comes to examples etc.

Can someone tell me if the above design is possible?  And could I use this inside of a play application?

Comment: Why don't you want to do words parsing inside Future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample for you.
Here Tokenizer takes seq of items to parse and gives them out to Parser to do the parsing.
Parser than reports back results to the Tokenizer.

```
import akka.actor._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

case object Go
case object Done
case object GoAway

class Tokenizer(items: Seq[String]) extends Actor {
  val kid = context.actorOf(Props[Parser])
  var tokens: List[String] = List.empty
  override def receive: akka.actor.Actor.Receive = {
    case Go => // start process
      items.foreach(kid ! _)
      kid ! GoAway
    case Done => // report results
      println(tokens.mkString(":"))
      self ! PoisonPill // shut down
    case s: String => // data from kid
      tokens = s :: tokens
  }
}

class Parser extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case GoAway =>
      sender ! Done
      self ! PoisonPill // or context.stop(self)
    case s: String =>
      s.split("\\.").foreach(sender ! _)
  }
}

object G extends App {

  val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("" +
    "akka.loglevel=DEBUG\n" +
    "akka.debug.lifecycle=on\n" +
    "akka.debug.receive=on\n" +
    "akka.debug.event-stream=on\n" +
    "akka.debug.unhandled=on\n" +
    ""
  )

  val system = ActorSystem("mine", config)
  val doer = system.actorOf(Props(new Tokenizer(Seq("191.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"))))

  doer ! Go

  system.shutdown()
  system.awaitTermination()

}
```

Comment: btw, how could I add logging using logback?

Comment: I'm getting this [INFO] message ```[INFO] [05/15/2014 14:51:23.293] [mine-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://mine/user/$a] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://mine/user/$a/$a#1727619572] to Actor[akka://mine/user/$a#1651939709] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.```

Comment: It is 2 Terminated messages - one from Parser, other from Tokenizer. And noone was subscribed to Terminated so the messages went to dead letters box. Plz ignore it for a while when you are getting familiar with Actors. You will see a lot of internal messages. If you want to receive the Terminated and other life cycle messages - subscribe using context.watch(kid) in the example code.